# Vuetify 3 change color in selection

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

hello everyone i am new to the front end , and i ve been learning vuejs for a long time and started to learn vuetify3 these days
i am facing a problem where in my code below , i am creatnig a navigation drawer , and my intention is to highlight the icon in red or any other color when its selected and keep the rest icons white

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer app color="#000000" mini-variant rail-width="110" class="d-flex justify-center mt-8">
        <v-avatar class="d-block text-center mx-auto mt-16 mb-16" size="100">
            <v-btn class="ma-2" fab color="white" rounded icon="mdi-basket" variant="outlined"></v-btn>
        </v-avatar>

        <v-card flat color="#151515">
            <v-layout>
                <v-list dense nav class="d-block mx-auto my-2" active-class="selected">
                    <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" class="my-8" v-slot="{ active }"
                        :ripple="false" @click="selectedItem = index" :value="index">
                        <v-icon :color="active ? 'red' : 'white'" :icon="item.icon" class="pa-auto" size="50"></v-icon>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-layout>
        </v-card>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
  
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        selectedItem: 0,
        items: [
            { icon: "mdi-home-outline" },
            { icon: "mdi-cart-outline" },
            { icon: "mdi-store-outline" },
            { icon: "mdi-calendar-check-outline" },
            { icon: "mdi-apps" },
        ],
    }),
};
</script>
  
<style scoped>
.selected {
    background-color: #6f0dff;
}
</style>
```

i dont see where the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slot prop passed to VListItem's [`#default`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#slots-default)  slot is named `isActive`, not just `active`, so you have to use `isActive` or rename it:

```html
<v-list-item
  ...
  v-slot="{ isActive: active }"
>
```

[playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)